# Automation testing for dynamic coordinates appearing in map using TestCafe or codeceptjs or cypress

Tags: dictionary, testing, ui-automation, testcafe, codeceptjs

I would like to automate the testing using testcafe or codeceptjs for a test case in which an item is displayed on correct address in map after clicking on it.
expected behavior for test case: User is taken to correct address on map after clicking the specific item

Comment: Could you please share an example of your test script? Did I understand you correctly that a map is scrolled programmatically on an event and you wish to check the coordinates it is scrolled to?

Comment: I can share you the use case.Go to google maps. Please put an address which you want to search. User is redirected to exact address on map with red icon after entering the required search so i would like to assert whether searched address or city/country/continent is same as displayed on map.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to test a Leaflet-based map using TestCafe: [How to test leaflet based maps using testcafe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56432686/how-to-test-leaflet-based-maps-using-testcafe).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have gone through leaflet based map article before. My only concern is putting the coordinates everytime in the test script. Is there any other way to avoid putting coordinates ?

Comment: Please describe your scenario in greater detail. What kind of values do you wish to assert in your test? From where are you going to get etalon values?