# How to fix TypeError: document.getElementById is not a function when running unit tests over files that use leaflet.js objects?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, leaflet, mocha.js

I have the exact same problem that is in this post [How can you unit test Leaflet JS maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38099276/how-can-you-unit-test-leaflet-js-maps/38101545)

I was unable to comment or add additional questions to this post so I apologize for the duplicate question.

```
GLOBAL.window = { screen: {} };
GLOBAL.document = {
    documentElement: {
        style: {}
    },
    getElementsByTagName: function () { return []; },
    createElement: function () { return {}; }
};
GLOBAL.navigator = {
    userAgent: 'nodejs',
    platform: 'nodejs'
};

GLOBAL.L = require('leaflet');
const assert = require('assert');
const config = require('../js/config.js')
```

config.js has the following in it.

```
const openstreetmap = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
});

const map = L.map('map', {
    center: [39, -105],
    zoom: 4,
    defaultExtentControl: true,
    zoomControl: false,
    layers: [openstreetmap]
});
```

I type mocha and get the following error:

TypeError: document.getElementById is not a function
    at get (C:\dev\apps\APP\node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet-src.js:2247:43)
    at NewClass._initContainer (C:\dev\apps\APP\node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet-src.js:4094:37)
    at NewClass.initialize (C:\dev\apps\APP\node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet-src.js:3131:8)
    at new NewClass (C:\dev\apps\APP\node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet-src.js:301:20)
    at Object.createMap [as map] (C:\dev\apps\APP\node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet-src.js:4718:9)
    at Object. (C:\dev\apps\APP\resources\js\config.js:12:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object. (C:\dev\apps\APP\resources\test\config_test.js:45:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at C:\Users\usr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:334:36
    at Array.forEach ()
    at Mocha.loadFiles (C:\Users\usr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:331:14)
    at Mocha.run (C:\Users\usr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:811:10)
    at Object.exports.singleRun (C:\Users\usr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:108:16)
    at exports.runMocha (C:\Users\usr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:142:13)
    at Object.exports.handler.argv [as handler] (C:\Users\usr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run.js:292:3)
    at Object.runCommand (C:\Users\usr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\node_modules\yargs\lib\command.js:242:26)
    at Object.parseArgs [as _parseArgs] (C:\Users\usr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:1104:24)
    at Object.parse (C:\Users\usr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:566:25)
    at Object.exports.main (C:\Users\usr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\cli.js:68:6)
    at Object. (C:\Users\usr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\bin\mocha:154:29)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)